# Wordpress Lightbox gallery don't display the “next” image

Tags: wordpress, lightbox, image-gallery

I'm very new to code, and I have a Wordpress gallery that display all thumbnail images correctly, but doesn't display the "next" image when the Lightbox is open, here is the code:

[Code preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl0dU.png)

This is the page link, under the GESTION SOCIAL tab: http://creativa.co/psp/el-puerto/

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can hide the next button using css.

Comment: Can you post the code text instead of posting an image please. Just looked at the image and can see a couple of things that could be an issue. 1. No closing tag for parent div (but this might just be cut off my the image) and 2. Where it says rel=lightbox[0] should probably be incremental, so the next one should be lightbox[1] then lightbox[2] etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response, here is the code, I had to upload a TXT file into Wetransfer because it contains too many characters to share here: 

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3e3d408dabbdcb1d989a519bb78ee74020180717142247/8db724c035fe7273f44ed57a3091baca20180717142248/af7d9d